# Запись значения radio в переменную jQuery

Tags: jquery

есть код который позволяет скрыть определенные элементы, при значение из списка. Как его переделать, чтобы он работал при radio?

```
<script> 
$(function() { 
$("#grid-5-5,#grid-6-6").hide(); 
$("#selector-8").on('change', function() { 
var a = $(this).val(); 
if(a == 0) { 
$("#grid-6-6,#grid-6-6").hide(); 
$("#grid-4-4").show(); 
} else if(a == 1) { 
$("#grid-4-4,#grid-6-6").hide(); 
$("#grid-5-5").show(); 
} else if(a == 2) { 
$("#grid-4-4,#grid-5-5").hide(); 
$("#grid-6-6").show(); 
} else if(a == 2) { 
$("#grid-4-4,#grid-5-5").hide(); 
$("#grid-6-6").show(); 
} 
}) 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Все тоже самое, отлавливайте события `$('input[type=radio]').on('change'....`

Comment: ("#input_radio-3").on('change', function() { 
Так не работает

Comment: точнее следующая строчка var a = $(this).val(); не записывает значение в переменную

Answer (score 0):

У Bас на странице есть повторяющиеся значения атрибута `id`. Выборка `$("#selector-8")` содержит максимум один элемент - первый найденный. Используйте `class` и соответствующий селектор `$(".selector-8")`.

```js
$(".selector-8").on('change', function() {
  var a = $(this).val();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="0" class="selector-8" name="selector-8" />
<input type="radio" value="1" class="selector-8" name="selector-8" />
<input type="radio" value="2" class="selector-8" name="selector-8" />
<input type="radio" value="3" class="selector-8" name="selector-8" />
```

или просто используйте `name`:

```js
$("input[type='radio'][name='selector-8']").on('change', function() {
  var a = $(this).val();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="0" name="selector-8" />
<input type="radio" value="1" name="selector-8" />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="selector-8" />
<input type="radio" value="3" name="selector-8" />
```